# Why can't I kill pthread via class object argument passed in

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I initiate a background thread to run my class function, the task is executed as an infinite loop until client side decide to stop. So since when create pthread the class object 'this' is passed into thread, I tried to cast it to class object but get a null object, can anyone explain to me why this is not workable ?

```
   void Camera::init()
   {
      typedef void *(*ThreadFuncPtr)(void *);
      this->quit=false;
      pthread_create(&acq, NULL, (ThreadFuncPtr)(&Camera::_acquireImages), this);
   }

   void Camera::stopAcquire()
   {
       this->quit=true;
   }

   void Camera::_acquireImages(void* ptr)
   {
       auto obj = (Camera*) ptr;  //obj after cast shows as NULL object
       while(!obj->quit){
       //do something
       }
       pthread_exit(NULL);
   }
```

Comment: Ted's answer below is probably right, but I recommend augmenting this question with a [mcve] so that he's provably correct and it's easier for future askers to draw the connection between the question and the answer. If he's right, add `-pedantic` to the compiler options and you'll get a nice warning message suggesting you take a closer look at `Camera::_acquireImages`, but if you remove the cast you'll get even better messages. The cast is hiding several things that you got wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So since when create pthread the class object 'this' is passed into
>   thread

`pthread_create` is a `C` function and expects the function signature to be `void* (*)(void*)` but it now has the signature `void (Camera::*)(void*)` so there are two errors: The function should return `void*` and it's also a non-static class member. To fix it, make the function return `void*` and make it `static`:

```
void Camera::init()
{
    this->quit = false;
    // now that the function has the correct signature, you don't need
    // to cast it (into something that it wasn't)
    pthread_create(&acq, NULL, &Camera::acquireImages, this);
}

void Camera::stopAcquire()
{
    this->quit = true;
}

/*static*/ void* Camera::acquiredImages(void* ptr) // make it static in the declaration
{
    Camera& obj = *static_cast<Camera*>(ptr);

    while(obj.quit == false){
        //do something
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

If you are using C++11 (or newer), you should however take a look at the standard `<thread>` which makes life much easier.

```
#include <thread>

struct Camera {
    void init() {
        quit = false;
        th = std::thread(&Camera::acquireImages, this);
    }
    ~Camera() {
        stopAcquire();
    }
    void acquireImages() {
        // no need for casting. "this" points at the object which started the thread
        while(quit == false) {
            std::cout << ".";
        }
    }
    void stopAcquire() {
        if(th.joinable()) {
            quit = true;
            th.join(); // hang here until the thread is done
        }
    }

    std::thread th{};
    bool quit = false;
};
```

Comment: This should save as yet another cautionary tale against casts: a lot of the time, they hide problems.